# rule based ngram mapping

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

ngram occuring together in a text need to map with dictionary remaining strings to others(O)

```
dict_ngram = {'Log':'c1','LOG entrie':'c2','log entrie block':'c3'}
sent = 'the user @ enter log = to validate log entrie in ,a log entrie block'
```

expected output:

```
[the-O,user-O,@ -O,enter-O,log-c1,=-O,to-O,validate-O,log entrie-c2, in-O, a-O, ,-O,log entrie block-c3]
```

Comment: Is there a question? Or do you just want to hire a developer to implement this?

Comment: @zvone, Ashok is a new contributor, probably he doesn't accept sarcasm very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the keys of `dict_ngram` in reverse order of the word counts in an alternation regex pattern, then use `re.findall` to tokenize the input string `sent`, and use `dict.get` to map the tokens to their values according to `dict_ngram` with `O` as a default value:

```
import re
dict_ngram = {k.lower(): v for k, v in dict_ngram.items()}
print('[%s]' % ','.join('-'.join((s.strip(), dict_ngram.get(s, 'O'))) for s in re.findall(r'%s|\S+' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(dict_ngram, key=len, reverse=True))), sent)))
```

This outputs:

```
[the-O,user-O,@-O,enter-O,log-c1,=-O,to-O,validate-O,log entrie-c2,in-O,,a-O,log entrie block-c3]
```

Comment: when there is special character like(= @ !) in the sentence the given logic unable to split and label its as 'O'

Comment: unable to map case sensitive strings

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean exactly. Can you update your question with sample input and expected output that demonstrate the two scenarios?

Comment: 1) Special characters in the sentence (@ = ,)unable to capture key values while finding and splitting the strings 2)  when the dictionary keys are case sensitive unable to match the strings in the sentence tried with re.ignorecase() but ended up with error.

Comment: instead of converting dict_ngrams to lower case cant we use "re.ignorecase" to be more genric?

Comment: No, because the `dict_ngrams` dict would then have mixed-case keys, which can't be looked up case-insensitively with the `dict_ngram.get` method. Besides, your expected output contain all lowercase keys anyway, so there's no downside to converting the keys to lowercase first.